# dynamically creating UIImageViews in a custom class method call in xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

i want to dynamically create and add to the view a uiimageview when a touch is registered within the frame of another uiimageview. i want these to stay on the screen and remain moveable when a touch is registered inside the frame of each uiimageview. here is the code i have now but it doesn't quite work right and is really glitchy(i.e. i can pick up a new view and it is created but it doesn't follow the touch properly as the touch is moved:

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
UIImageView *onePieceCopy = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
onePieceCopy.frame = CGRectMake(currentPos.x, currentPos.y, 75, 75);
[self addSubview:onePieceCopy];
if (CGRectContainsPoint([onePieceCopy frame], position)) {
    onePieceCopy.center = position;
[self bringSubviewToFront:onePieceCopy];
} 
[onePieceCopy release];
```

this code is in a switch statement that is in a method that is called when a touch is registered inside the frame of a designated UIImageView.

the ideal result would be a system not unlike a map editor where you drag parts from a 'staging' area and onto the map, if that makes any sense. does anyone know how to do this or how i can better my code to get the desired result

Comment: as an example the game crystal defenders for ipad has the system i'm trying to implement, where you drag your units from the right side of the screen onto the playing field.

Answer (score 0):

[WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) (must be a registered developer).  Watch "Session 104 - Advanced Scroll View Techniques".  At about minute 40 they do a nice pick and place of a uiimage.