# unique naming of objects as they are added to an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

how would i go about uniquely naming an object and adding it to an nsmutablearray most likely in a for loop?

Comment: Why do you need unique name if you can use object's index in array to identify it?

Comment: Why would you want to name it - what is the object in the array for in the first place?
A bit more detail would help

Comment: doesn't it need a name to be added to the array? like aren't you supposed to say:

[theArray addObject:theObject]; where theObject is the name of an actual object? i guess i don't totally understand how NSMutableArrays work

Comment: @woody i am creating an array that i can dynamically add UIImagViews that would be managed in a global manner, so i can have objects created when a touch is registered on a view. see this post for what exactly i want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598014/dynamically-creating-uiimageviews-in-a-custom-class-method-call-in-xcode

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing objects and variables. Variables have names; objects don't unless you give them some `name` instance variable. More to the point, the same variable can reference different objects at different times. Given some collection of objects `collection`:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

for (id item in collection) {
    [array addObject:item];
}
```

This will create a mutable array with all the objects in `collection`, with the `item` variable pointing to a different object from `collection` on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to uniquely name instances then instead of an array how about using a NSDictionary? Then you can grab the array of keys from it. Run through this key array to get the name of a particular instance and then use that key to get the actual object instance from the dictionary.

Comment: thats a good idea, but unfortunately i don't believe i can do what i want which is to create an array (or NSDictionary in this case) and then create outlets for each instance and @synthesize them so they can be acted upon elsewhere, if that makes any sense